# Calculate Checksum android

Tags: android, string, byte, checksum

I need to calculate the checksum of some strings that I need to send via bluetooth. There are 5 strings that I need to send, so, I need to create a function to calculate the checksum.

I need help creating the function to do this.

These are the strings:

```
/**String to calculate the Checksum*/
    String message_part1 = send_command+" "+num_byte_trama1+" "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_1+" "+sendValue1;
    String message_part2 = send_command+" "+num_byte_trama1+" "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_2+" "+sendValue2;
    String message_part3 = send_command+" "+num_byte_trama1+" "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_3+" "+sendValue3;
    String message_part4 = send_command+" "+num_byte_trama2+" "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_save_request;
    String message_part5 = send_command+" "+num_byte_trama2+" "+num_byte_variable+" "+pos_reg_save_status;

    /**Full message*/
    String message_full1 = start_thread+" "+message_part1+" "+Checksum;
    String message_full2 = start_thread+" "+message_part2+" "+Checksum;
    String message_full3 = start_thread+" "+message_part3+" "+Checksum;
    String message_full4 = start_thread+" "+message_part4+" "+Checksum;
    String message_full5 = start_thread+" "+message_part5+" "+Checksum;
```

So, I need to create a function that reads a string, gets this string's bytes, calculates the Checksum, and then converts this value to hex.

This is what i've done. I don't know if it is correcto, and I still haven't done the int to hex conversion:

```
    private String CalcChecksum (String message) {

    byte[] byte_calc = message.getBytes();        
    int checksum = 0;

    for (int byte_index = 0; byte_index < byte_calc.length; byte_index++) {
        checksum += byte_calc[byte_index];
    }
    return checksum;
}
```

Comment: Posted what i've done

Answer (score 0):

I used the .hashCode (String) method simply to create hashcode of an sms body+date, in order to avoid duplication during parsing sms.
This returns a 32 bit (signed) integer. For me this provides enough entropy to accept it as uniqId for a message, this is quite fast calculation and platform independent.